# Android animation side effect: button changes its shape when animating color

Tags: android

all the code I posted below works like I wanted, just putting it for the reference and maybe someone who would like to achieve similar things. It is simple and quite well commented.

So there, I am developing an application where I have few round buttons created dynamically based on xml drawable resource defined like this:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<shape xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android" android:shape="rectangle" >
<corners
    android:radius="25dp"
    />
<solid
    android:color="#0000FF"
    />
<padding
    android:left="0dp"
    android:top="0dp"
    android:right="0dp"
    android:bottom="0dp"
    />
<size
    android:width="50dp"
    android:height="50dp"
    />
</shape>
```

And it is used to create buttons stored in an array (`gameButtons`) like below. (As you see I am placing buttons randomly on a screen). It works fine:

```
for(int i = 0; i < (numberOfButtons); i++)
        {
        //create a button:
        Button oneBtn = new Button(this);

        //get layout reference:
        RelativeLayout rl = (RelativeLayout) findViewById(R.id.game_window);
        RelativeLayout.LayoutParams params = new RelativeLayout.LayoutParams(btnSize, btnSize);

        //get screen size:
        Display display = getWindowManager().getDefaultDisplay();
        Point size = new Point();
        display.getSize(size);
        int width = size.x;
        int height = size.y;

        //randomize button's position:
        Random r = new Random();
        int randX = r.nextInt(height - btnSize);
        int randY = r.nextInt(width - btnSize);

        params.leftMargin = randY;
        params.topMargin = randX;

        //set button's parameteres:
        oneBtn.setId(i);
        oneBtn.setText(String.valueOf(i));

        //make the button round, based on drawable/buttonshape.xml:
        oneBtn.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.buttonshape);

        //add button to the view:
        gameButtons[i] = oneBtn;
        rl.addView(oneBtn, params);


        }
```

Then I want to apply an animation to these buttons. The animation just makes the button blinking by changing its color few times (blue->yellow->blue-> ...)
This animation works fine as well (does what I want)

```
private void changeButtonColor(final Button button){

    int animationTime = 800;

    //set colors rgb->int
    int blueInt = Color.rgb(0,0,255);
    int yellowInt = Color.rgb(255,255,0);

    //craete an animation:
    ValueAnimator anim = new ValueAnimator();
    anim.setIntValues(blueInt, yellowInt, blueInt);
    anim.setEvaluator(new ArgbEvaluator());

    anim.addUpdateListener(new ValueAnimator.AnimatorUpdateListener() {
        @Override
        public void onAnimationUpdate(ValueAnimator valueAnimator) {

        //animate button's color:
        button.setBackgroundColor((Integer)valueAnimator.getAnimatedValue());
        }
    });

    //final settings to animation an start:
    anim.setInterpolator(new LinearInterpolator());
    anim.setDuration(animationTime);
    anim.start();
}
```

And buttons blink like I wanted except the fact that, when I am invoking `changeButtonColor()` my buttons change their shape into a square.

It seems like above animation overrides what `setBackgroundResource()` does however, I have tried to prevent this in many ways by putting `setBackgroundResource()` within the animation but no result.

Any suggestions how to eliminate this side effect ?

Answer (score 0):

Actually, I don't know the reason for this behavior but I have implemented a workaround. Instead of animating color change I am changing the background resource.

So I have defined another resource like blue button but with yellow color:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<shape xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android" android:shape="rectangle" >
<corners
    android:radius="25dp"
    />
<solid
    android:color="#FFFF00"
    />
<padding
    android:left="0dp"
    android:top="0dp"
    android:right="0dp"
    android:bottom="0dp"
    />
<size
    android:width="50dp"
    android:height="50dp"
    />
</shape>
```

and then I am just animating the resource change:

```
private void changeButtonColor(final Button button){

    int animationTime = 800;

    int yellowResource = R.drawable.buttonshape_yellow;
    int blueResource = R.drawable.buttonshape;

    ValueAnimator anim = new ValueAnimator();
    anim.setIntValues(blueResource, yellowResource, blueResource, yellowResource, blueResource);
    anim.setEvaluator(new ArgbEvaluator());

    anim.addUpdateListener(new ValueAnimator.AnimatorUpdateListener() {
        @Override
        public void onAnimationUpdate(ValueAnimator valueAnimator) {
      button.setBackgroundResource((Integer)valueAnimator.getAnimatedValue());
        }
    });
    anim.setInterpolator(new LinearInterpolator());
    anim.setDuration(animationTime);
    anim.start();
}
```

thanks for helping anyway